# How to save dataframe to excel with unique name each time script is run

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

Each month I do a piece of work which is just straight copy paste from Google Big Query to Excel, save the file in a shared drive and then email that file to a list of contacts.

I'm trying to automate this in Python using the below code but each month I need to change the name of the file manually, is there a way I can have this automatically change based on date I run the script ?

```
import pandas_gbq
project_id= "myproject"
sql = """
SELECT *
FROM 'myproject.mytable'"""
df_1 = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(sql, project_id)

df_1.to_excel (r'\\companyshare\directory1\directory2\ Summary Table April 2022.xlsx', index = None, header=True) 

import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'firstname.lastname@company.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test email via python'
mail.Body = '''Test '''
mail.Attachments.Add(r'\\companyshare\directory1\directory2\ Summary Table April 2022.xlsx', index = None, header=True) 
mail.Send()
```

So with the above code in mind, each month I need to change the name of 'Summary Table April 2022' to the current month and year. Can this be done automatically when I save the df to excel and then attach the excel to my email ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` to get the current time when you run it, then replace it in the naming of the file

```py
from datetime import datetime

df_1.to_excel(r'\\companyshare\directory1\directory2\ Summary Table %s.xlsx'%(datetime.now().strftime('%B %Y')), index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks fam-woodpecker